# Can I use NuGet with a project built in an earlier version of Visual Studio WITHOUT upgrading the solution?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

I have an inherited project in Visual Studio 2008 for which I need to create a build plan.  Since the developer left no unit tests, I'm really, really hesitant to upgrade the project to VS 2010.

That said, my solution for NOT storing binaries in our source control mechanism (SVN) is to use a Nuget repository that I host.  Ideally, what I would do is:

1. WITHOUT upgrading the VS 2008 project, remove the references and instead insert a *.pkg reference
2. Host the dlls in a NuGet Package on my local NuGet server
3. Let my Build rip so to speak.

Note that I have Visual Studio 2010 and NuGet installed - I just don't want to run the upgrade wizard.  How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Sharp Develop 4.1 to install packages in older solutions ( 2005/2008)
Sharp Develop doesn't change the version of Visual Studio.

[website](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/)

I think Visual Studio 2010 has to be installed with the plugin, but you already did that :-)